# Swift - Execute SSH Command in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ssh

I want to execute a Shell Command in my Swift Application.
I read that i can't use NSTask, because there is no built in SSH in the iPhone. Now my question is how i can implement this without NSTask.

Comment: I've heard some good things about [libssh-2-for-iOS](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS) but haven't had the occasion to try it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own app you may want to look into an iOS app called 'Workflow'. It includes a module called 'Run Script Over SSH' which does exactly what the title states.

Answer (score 0):

Any use of API that forks and spawns a new process is disallowed by the App Store rules, so if you want to do this for an app you plan to submit, the short answer is that you can't.

`NSTask` and the `exec*(3)` family of C library functions certainly exist on iOS, but they aren't public API.

If you need SSH functionality, you need to find a library that provides that functionality to pass App Store review.

Comment: I dont want to submit the App to the App Store. I just want a App for me personally that starts and stops a Service that runs on my local Server.

Comment: Two options, then: 1. Use an SSH client library to make the connection. 2. Jailbreak your phone, install an SSH client (if one isn't installed for you), and use `NSTask` or `exec*(3)`.

Comment: can you recommand a ssh library? i'd like to avoid jailbreaking my phone